# From a kmalloc buffer, get corresponding array of pages and offsets

Tags: c, linux, paging, kmalloc

I am working on a new socket that sits on top of TCP sockets, and for performance reasons, I want to call `tcp_sendpage` instead of `tcp_sendmsg` (`tcp_sendmsg` would copy my data unnecessarily). However, my input is a kmalloc'ed buffer that can be anywhere from a few bytes to spanning several pages. `tcp_sendpage` wants a `struct page*`, `offset`, and `size` as input. How do I convert my buffer to something that `tcp_sendpage` likes to see?

I have discovered `virt_to_page` and `offset_in_page`; however, that only converts a single address rather than the entire buffer. In my mind what I need is a function that converts my (physically contiguous, as promised by `kmalloc`) buffer into an array of pages and offsets